# Google Script adding cell name on a formula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new to google script, and learn a lot by searching through this site, but now I'm trying to figure out how can I add a cell name (A1, A2, .....) to a formula using google script.

Please see my sample here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mttb7dD4RvfXmNt3xGe7cAR6SAXB7Tom97vNOK-YQB0/edit?usp=sharing

On column C you will see "=A16+1" but it should be like "=A2+1" since I'm on row 2

here is the google script code

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("test1");
  var range = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var valueToWatch = "y";

  var searchRange = sheet.getRange("A1:A" + sheet.getLastRow()); // Modified
  // get the values in an array
  var values = searchRange.getValues();
  // examine the values in the array
  var i = [];
  for (var y = 0; y < values.length; y++) {
    if (values[y][0] == valueToWatch) {
      i.push("C" + (y + 1)); // Modified
    }
  }

  //sheet.getRangeList(i).setValue("this is a test");

  var data = [];
  for (var x = 0; x < values.length; x++) {
    data = ['=A' + (x + 1).toString() + '&"1"'];
  }

  sheet.getRangeList(i).setFormula(data);

}
```

Comment: Small suggestion: If you indent your code, it would be easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Upon reviewing your code, it looks like you want to add formula to column `C` if the same row in column `A` has **y**.

Try this code below:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("test1");
  var valueToWatch = "y";
  var searchRange = sheet.getRange("A1:A" + sheet.getLastRow()); // Modified
  var values = searchRange.getValues();
  var i = [];
  for (var y = 0; y < values.length; y++) {
    if(values[y][0] == valueToWatch){
      i.push("C" + (y + 1));
    }else{
      i.push('');
    }
  }

  var data = [];
  for (var x=0; x < i.length; x++){
    if(i[x] != ''){
      var rowNum = i[x].replace( /^\D+/g, '');
      data.push(['=A' + rowNum + '&"1"' ])
    }else{
      data.push(['']);
    }
  }
  sheet.getRange("C1:C" + sheet.getLastRow()).setFormulas(data);
}
```

**Example:**

[image]

### **Reference:**

- [Range.setFormulas(formulas)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulasformulas)

Comment: Hi @Nikko, this is very useful, I can't upvote right now but I will once reputation is 15 already thanks for this. And also I've been trying to copy a cell value from a same row with different column, any reference I can check for it?

Comment: @reks - was my answer above able to fix your issue? If yes, please click the accept button on the left (check icon).  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: @reks - I would suggest you to create another post regarding "copy a cell value from a same row with different column"  with detailed information just like your post above. This will help the community to visualize your issue and will help you get  better answers.